# Javascript Electron Sqlite insert

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on my code and why it may not be working. I am running nodejs 6+ with an electron wrapper.

dependencies for the sqlite are "sqlite3": "^3.1.8

I am managing to list and display the data in rows without issue but on the insert function or search function it is falling over. I must be doing something wrong.

```
function insertNewVeh() {
       db.all("INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES ('" +
       document.getElementById('regNo').value + "','" +
       document.getElementById('firstName').value + "','" +
       document.getElementById('lastName').value + 
       "')", function(err, rows) {
          console.log.msg;
          })
        }
insertNewVeh();


     function srchReg() {
        var regNo = document.getElementById("regNo").value
        db.all("SELECT ALL FROM VEHICLES WHERE regNo = " + regNo + ""), function(err, rows) {
            var reg = document.getElementById("newVehicle").value
            rows.forEach(function (row) {  
            console.log.msg;
            document.getElementById('sReg').innerHTML =
                "<div>Total</div>"
                })
            };
        };
        srchReg();
```

and the functions

```
function srchDiv() {
    document.getElementById('rSrch').innerHTML = 
              "<form>" +
              "<input type=\"search\" id=\regNo\" placeholder=\"What are you looking for?\">" + 
             "<button id=\"subSrch\">Search</button>" +
              "</form>";
     document.getElementById('subSrch').addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          srchReg();
        });
}
srchDiv();

window.onload = function addVeh() {
       document.getElementById('nVeh1').innerHTML =
        "<form>" +
              "<div class=\"row\">" +
                    "<label for=\"firstName\" id=\"firstName\">First Name</label>" +
                    "<input id=\"firstName\" name=\"firstName\" type=\"text\"/>" +
               "</div>" +
               "<div class=\"row\">" +
                    "<label for=\"lastName\" id=\"lastName\">Last Name</label>" +
                    "<input id=\"lastName\" name=\"lastName\" type=\"text\"/>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class=\"row\">" +
                    "<label for=\"address1\" id=\"address1\">Address 1</label>" +
                     "<input id=\"address1\" name=\"address1\" type=\"text\" />" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class=\"row\">" +
                    "<label for=\"address2\" id=\"address2\">Address 2</label>" +
                    "<input id=\"address2\" name=\"address2\" type=\"text\"/>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class=\"row\">" +
                    "<label for=\"town\" id=\"town\">Town</label>" +
                    "<input id=\"town\" name=\"town\" type=\"text\"/>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class=\"row\">" +
                    "<label for=\"postcode\" id=\"postcode\">Post Code</label>" +
                    "<input id=\"postcode\" name=\"postcode\" type=\"text\"/>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class=\"row\">" +
                    "<label for=\"telephone\" id=\"telephone\">Telephone</label>" +
                    "<input id=\"telephone\" name=\"telephone\" type=\"tel\"/>" +
                "</div>";
        document.getElementById('nVeh2').innerHTML =
                "<div class=\"row\">" +
                    "<label for=\"regNo\" id=\"regNo\">regNo</label>" +
                    "<input id=\"regNo\" name=\"regNo\" type=\"text\"/>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class=\"row\">" +
                  "<button type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\" id=\"addV\"/>Add</button>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</form>";
       document.getElementById('addV').addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            insertNewVeh();
            });
        }
addVeh();
```

I am relatively sure it's a syntax error somewhere but can't see it as I am still new to javascript. In either function the search doesnt work, nor does it insert anything to the database.

Comment: Are there any error messages in your javascript console?

Comment: No, when the button is clicked the call stack just states: Navigated to file:///xxx/app/index.html? So it looks like its not parsering the data.

Comment: The other I have modified slightly, and it is stating the same Navigated to file:///xxx/app/index.html?firstName=&lastName=&address1=&address2=&town=&postcode=&telephone=&regNo=asdasd but on this one the data is being parsered

Comment: I am also getting an error on another statement not pasted here Uncaught TypeError: rows.forEach is not a function. Though the function is actually running succesfuly.

Comment: It is still hard to say what's going on exactly. My next guess would be; I see a form. When you press 'submit' you are submitting your form. The function InsertNewVeh should prevent submitting the form by return 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

Note the 'return false', since your are submitting a form

```
function insertNewVeh() {
    const self = this
    db.serialize(
        function () {
            let stmnt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES (?, ?, ?)')
            stmnt.run(document.getElementById('regNo').value, document.getElementById('firstName').value, document.getElementById('lastName').value, function () {
                stmnt.finalize(function () {
                    // Here goes your callback, if you need one
                    // self.doSomeThing()
                })
            })
        }
    )
    return false
}
```

Comment: I am learning as I go along with a little trial and error. I will modify my function and see what happens.